# How to test FaaS / SaaS in and out

Tags: automated-tests, devops, saas, faas

- How Function as a Service OR Software as a Service can be tested thoroughly.
  What is the nitty gritty involved in testing FaaS in and out ? Below are some of the pointers that come to my mind but would like to expand on this list.
- Automated Tests
- Negative Tests
- Security Tests
- Checking access restrictions
- Scalability

2. Above items are focused on activities which can be performed locally or in testing environments but would like to consider scenarios if it should be or can be tested after deployment to Cloud.
3. How can Kubernetes pods be tested for scalability ?

Answer (score -1):

There are a few different ways that you can test FaaS / SaaS in and out of the cloud tools. One way is to use a tool like SoapUI or Postman to make calls to the API and check the responses. Another way is to use a tool like Selenium to automate the UI and check the results.